# How to open PDF file in Chrome via command in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, google-chrome, pdf

Chrome can view PDF file, so I decide to make it as my default PDF viewer. However, I do not know how to open PDF file in chrome via my terminal emulator.

I have tried a command `google-chrome example.pdf`, but it failed while the address is not `file:///path/to/example.pdf/` but `http://example.pdf/`.

My English is not good, so you can edit the question if necessary.

Thank you!

Updated: Sorry for I did not mention that **the solution must be effective for GNU/Linux.**

Comment: Did you try "google-chrome file:///path/to/example.pdf"?

Comment: @JanDoggen It works, but it is too boring while I can not press tab to complete it quickly. Is there any better method?

Comment: Works for me. What Chrome version are you running? Try `google-chrome ./example.pdf`, perhaps — `example.pdf` looks like a domain name but as soon as you add a `/` it looks like a file name.

Comment: @acgtyrant I don't know Linux, but can't you make script saying  "google-chrome file:///path/to/%1.pdf" (like a Windows batch file) ?

Comment: @Gilles `google-chrome ./example.pdf` still turns in to `http://./texlive-zh-cn.pdf`.
@JanDoggen No, I do not have any idea:)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on pdf file and change opens with application to chrome and apply the changes.
For more information [see this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43764/how-to-enable-google-chrome-as-your-default-pdf-reader-the-easy-way/)
Also using command line it can be done.Just use below command line

```
<path to chrome.exe> <path to pdf file>
```

Comment: Sorry for I did not mention that the background is for Linux, however thanks anyway.